What software can I use to refresh a "Aw, Snap!" page on Chromium from out-of-memory?
What software can I use to refresh only a "Aw, Snap!" tab on Chromium from out-of-memory?

I am the maintainer of the page (can modify JavaScript code)
the page acts like a web server. It receives requests via WebSockets, and it processes the request. Sometimes, too many requests come in sucession and too much memory is used up, causing the tab crashes. Some of the requests use 1 MB memory, and some use 1 GB memory, so rate limiting to n concurrent requests won't work.

the page will be left unattended after the inital page load, so it must be an automation


it should only refresh the tab when it shows "Aw, Snap!", never when it's still working perfectly fine


Lets see if I understood that: you have JavaScript Code. That code runs in a Chromium tab. Sometimes, it runs out of memory. If it runs out of memory, it displays "Aw snap" (where?). If it displays "Aw snap", you want the tab to be refreshed, i.e. basically a restart of your application. Is that correct?

@ThomasWeller you have it correct. I will also open that page and leave it unattended since I don't need to watch it work. The default Chromium "Aw, Snap" (automatically replaces my page when memory limit reached): https://i.sstatic.net/3qQoKhlD.png
